# "smaller" keyword(?) in OCaml

Tags: ocaml, keyword

In the solutions for the tutorials for OCaml form [here](http://ocaml.org/learn/tutorials/99problems.html), the one regarding eliminating consecutive duplicates of list elements, the code is written as such:

```
let rec compress = function
   | a :: (b :: _ as t) -> if a = b then compress t else a :: compress t
   | smaller -> smaller;;
```

I've never seen the keyword(?) "smaller" before, I looked up online but failed to find it. Although in this case, I understand its meaning, I still wonder if anyone can explain more about it. Thanks!

Comment: Would it help if I told you that `smaller -> smaller` could be replaced with `x -> x`? :)

Comment: Constructors, not keywords, are used in match statements. That's a binding you've got there - a variable name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`smaller` is not a keyword, it's an identifier, just like `a`, `b` and `t` are on the line before.

The pattern `smaller` simply matches any possible value (that has not been matched by any previous pattern) and gives it the name `smaller`.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to read the chapter [Lists and Patterns](https://realworldocaml.org/v1/en/html/lists-and-patterns.html) in the book [Real World OCaml](https://realworldocaml.org/).

Comment: This answer is better to be a comment.